# Should I create new account in AWS and Heroku for my clients?

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku

It's the first time I'm doing a Rails project for a client, and I have a doubt. The person/company will have their own credentials right? (Domain, Server, Storage). So, should I create another Heroku account and Amazon S3 Account for the person myself? It's seems logical, but Amazon for example, will not allow other person than the owner itself to register new AWS account, because it's linked to Amazon.com. What do you guys normally do?

I did a research and couldn't find appropriate answers about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The person/company will have their own credentials right? (Domain, Server, Storage)

That will depend on the client. Sometimes they do, sometimes they don't, sometimes they have 2/3 of those things.

If the client doesn't have anything, it's up to you to decide whether you want to:

- Have the project on your own account and manage their project forever (for a fee, for example)
- Sit down with them at the beginning of the project and setup their account + a subaccount for yourself.

I suggest you talk about this openly with your client and decide together on the best path forward.